# Explode content with PHP in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, explode

I've created a WordPress starter theme as my first project to make it free and downloadable from all, but I have actually a little problem.

I have a create a shortcode to add into text editor from WordPress admin to create in a good way price box:

```
function price-gold($atts, $content = null){
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'title' =>  '',
    'price' =>  '',
    'plan'  =>  '',
    'color' =>  '',
    'btn_target'=>'',
    'btn_url'=>'',
    'btn_text'=>'',
    'btn_style' => '',
    'effect' => '' ), $atts ) );

    if($effect != "" && $effect != "none"){
        $output = '<div class="price animate '.esc_attr($type).'" data-effect="'.esc_attr($effect).'">';
    }else{
        $output = '<div class="price '.esc_attr($type).'">';
    }

    if($color == '' || $color == 'theme'){
        $color = 'btn-theme';
    }

    $output .= '<div class="price-header">';
    if($title != ''){
        $output .= '<h4 class="price-title">'.esc_attr($title).'</h4>';
    }
    if($price != ''){
        $output .= '<h1 class="price-num '.esc_attr($color).'-t">'.esc_attr($price).'</h1>';
    }
    if($plan != ''){
        $output .= '<div class="price-plan">'.esc_attr($plan).'</div>';
    }
    $output .= '</div>';


    $output .= '<div class="price-content">';
    $output .= '<ul>';
    $output .= '<li class="price-rig">';
    $output .= do_shortcode($content);
    $output .= '</li>';
    $output .= '</ul>';
    $output .= '</div>';

    $output .= '<div class="price-footer">';
    $output .= do_shortcode('[button style="'.esc_attr($btn_style).'" color="'.esc_attr($color).'" target="'.esc_attr($btn_target).'" url="'.esc_attr($btn_url).'" text="'.esc_attr($btn_text).'"]');
    $output .= '</div>';

    $output .= '</div>';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('price', 'price-gold');
```

$content = text that into text editor will be inserted.

Now it works, but I have `$output .= do_shortcode($content);` that is in one `<li>`, I need to explode `$content` and put every content line into a `<li> </li>`.

I have make some test but I haven't had a right result, I'm really confused, is there anyone who can give me a hand with some code?

Comment: Please what you wrote when you were trying to explode the $content

Comment: Can you give us an example of what $content would be when passed into this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to split $content into lines presumably based on `\n`? If so, you need to to explode the string on '\n', and implode the result using `</li><li>`.

```
$output = do_shortcode(implode("</li><li>", explode("\n", $content)))
```

Obviously if you wish to split $content based on something other than lines (like, spans, divs, p elements, or br's) then change the `\n` accordingly.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much, it works correct, i used <br> tag to divide content . Thank you sirlark!

Comment: Problem is if i need to split $content using <br> tag for some data and other tag, for example <span> for other data . For example i have this string into $content Some Words - 9 letters  , i have correctly splitted "Some Words in <li> tag, but if i need to split 9 letters into other tag ? i have tried to make a double implode and explode using for implode <span> and for exploder "-" but doesn't works .

Comment: You're heading deep into the territory of full HTML parsing there, but you might still be able to pull it off with basic PHP functions. First, you can't 'double explode' assuming you mean something like `explode("<li>", explode("<br/>", $content))` because the inner explode returns a list not a string. You are limited to one explode only. You could replace all `<` characters with `(MARK)<`, then run the result though `strip_tags`, which would homogenise the splitting factor to '(MARK)', which you can then explode on.

Comment: Some other thoughts: for tags that are closed separately (<li> </li>, <p> </p>, etc) you probably want to strip out the close tags before substituting with '(MARK)'. Also, if you have a limited set of tags you need to worry about, you could go through a series of implode("(MARK)", explode("<tag>", $content)), and then finally explode on (MARK) again.